# rawtohex function with case statement in oracle

Tags: oracle

```
rawtohex(case 
            when ad.AGENT_TYPE in ('ROLE_CUSTOMER_L0',
                                   'ROLE_CUSTOMER_L1',
                                   'ROLE_CUSTOMER_L2') 
            then cinf.STR_CARD_NUMBER 
            else ad.STR_CARD_NUMBER
          ) end as CARD_NUMBER
     )
```

`Rawtohex` function is not working giving syntax error

Comment: can you show the error please, and also your full SQL statement

Comment: Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

You misplaced the closing bracket

```
select to_char(case
         when 'x' = 'x'
         then 'x'
         else 'y')
        end as bla
from dual;

ORA-00905: missing keyword
00905. 00000 -  "missing keyword"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 27 Column: 18

select to_char(case
         when 'x' = 'x'
         then 'x'
         else 'y'
        end) as bla
from dual;

BLA
---
x
```